# Sqlx Get with prepared statements

Tags: postgresql, go, sqlx

I am trying to fetch some data from postgress table using prepared statements

If I try with database.Get() everything is returned.

Table:

```
create table accounts
(
  id            bigserial not null
    constraint accounts_pkey
    primary key,
  identificator text      not null,
  password      text      not null,
  salt          text      not null,
  type          smallint  not null,
  level         smallint  not null,
  created_at    timestamp not null,
  updated       timestamp not null,
  expiry_date   timestamp,
  qr_key        text
);
```

Account struct:

```
type Account struct {
    ID            string `db:"id"`
    Identificator string `db:"identificator"`

    Password   string         `db:"password"`
    Salt       string         `db:"salt"`
    Type       int            `db:"type"`
    Level      int            `db:"level"`
    ExpiryDate time.Time      `db:"expiry_date"`
    CreatedAt  time.Time      `db:"created_at"`
    UpdateAt   time.Time      `db:"updated_at"`
    QrKey      sql.NullString `db:"qr_key"`
}
```

BTW i tried using ? instead of $1 & $2

```
stmt, err := database.Preparex(`SELECT * FROM accounts where identificator = $1 and type = $2`)

if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
accounts := []account.Account{}
err = stmt.Get(&accounts, "asd", 123)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

The error I get is

> "errorMessage": "scannable dest type slice with \u003e1 columns (10) in result",

In the table there are no records I tried to remove all fields except the ID from Account (struct), however it does not work.

Comment: run the query in prepare directly in pgadmin. Check how many rows it returns or it returns a single row. Because Get is used to select single record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation for sqlx described [Get and Select](http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/) as:

> `Get` and `Select` use rows.Scan on scannable types and rows.StructScan on
>   non-scannable types. They are roughly analagous to QueryRow and Query,
>   where Get is useful for fetching a single result and scanning it, and
>   Select is useful for fetching a slice of results:

For fetching a single record use `Get`.

```
stmt, err := database.Preparex(`SELECT * FROM accounts where identificator = $1 and type = $2`)
var account Account
err = stmt.Get(&account, "asd", 123)
```

If your query returns more than a single record use `Select` with statement as:

```
stmt, err := database.Preparex(`SELECT * FROM accounts where identificator = $1 and type = $2`)
var accounts []Account
err = stmt.Select(&accounts, "asd", 123)
```

In your case if you use `stmt.Select` instead if `stmt.Get`. It will work.

Comment: It worked for us, but we used `:` instead of `$`